# Delete Azure Active Directory "Default Directory"

Tags: azure

When my account was a free trial I created an Azure AD now called "Default Directory".

Now I am using a production subscription, I still have the "Default Directory" which appears to be shared between my subscriptions, but is only visible to my user account, not any other administrators on my subscription.

I don't appear to be able to delete this directory, or make it available to other administrator.

How can I either delete it, or let other users administer it?

Answer (score 4):

(Better late than never, maybe it will help the next person.)

<strike>Currently, you can't remove a directory. You can, however, add others to it.</strike> **Edit**: you can now delete directories, as long as your currently signed-in user is the last remaining user (and a few other restrictions).

A key point to make before getting into the details is that an Azure Active Directory 'Global Administrator' is only administrator of the directory itself. There is no relation to the Azure subscription, nor does it have an effect on who is admin or co-admin of the subscription.

For others to see your directory when they log in to the Azure portal, you need add them as users of the directory: Azure portal > ACTIVE DIRECTORY > 'Default Directory' > USERS > Add user. You will have the choice of adding their Microsoft Account (MSA) or an Azure Active Directory user.

Tip: You can change the display name of the directory to something more descriptive under the 'CONFIGURE' section.

Comment: The ability to delete directories has since been added to the Azure Management Portal.

Comment: Yes, it has. Made appropriate edit.

Comment: Some explanation other than 'you can now do this' would be useful

Comment: @johnstaveley Have you tried clicking on "Delete directory" in the Azure portal -> Azure Active Directory?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret, it is greyed out